# How to cast a literal to mut in rust without using a temporary variable?

Tags: rust

this is for passing to a function taking `*mut T`

```
pub unsafe fn a() {
    std::ptr::write_volatile(&581684,1);
}
```

Which of course results in

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
--> src/lib.rs:2:30
  |
2 | std::ptr::write_volatile(&581684,1);
  | ^^^^^^^ types differ in mutability
  |
 = note: expected raw pointer `*mut _`
              found reference `&{integer}`
```

What s the correct way to do this in one line?

Comment: “using a variable which might keep it s register when even after being no longer needed” What year is this? Compilers have been able to reason about registers allocation for decades.

Comment: @mcarton except that if the codebase is large, some trivial optimizations ends up not being made in order to not take too much compile time or too much memory. So it s better to let the compiler know that the value is a one time directly.

Comment: Register allocation is a local optimization. It doesn't matter whether your code base is large or not. And no compiler that I know of would skip such common optimization in order to save compile time on big projects, and I wouldn't be surprised at all if information about the origin of a value (explicit variable or not) is lost altogether by the time it arrives to the register allocator anyway.

Comment: @user2284570 mcarton is right, using the reference to a value will probably compile to the same intermediate representation as using a temporary variable. But the variable is a red herring - the real concern is that the code does the wrong thing, which I addressed in my answer.

Comment: @mcarton llvm? On gcc for example, this requires tuning various `--param` internal which can results in hundreds of gigabytes of ram usage. Better to get a single llvm instruction which will results in no registers being used at all for the destination address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `&mut 581684`, which you can cast to a pointer:

```rust
// write 581684_i32 on the stack and then overwrite it with 1_i32
std::ptr::write_volatile(&mut 581684 as *mut _, 1);
```

But that code is highly suspect because it creates a temporary `i32` value on the stack, fills it with `581684`, and passes its address to `write_volatile()` to fill it with `1` instead. Since the address is on the stack, chosen at run-time, and in no way special, there is simply no point to write `1` there only to discard the location.

If your intention was to write the value 1 to a fixed address, possibly one observed by hardware, then `&ADDRESS` is not what you want. Instead, you should use the `as` operator to cast the address *as an integer* to a pointer, much like you'd do it in C or C++. Assuming you want to write a single byte, it'd look like this:

```
// store 1u8 at address 581684
std::ptr::write_volatile(581684 as *mut _, 1u8);
```